# How to obtain hydrophobic Doxorubicin from its hydrochloride salt?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I have read literatures on dissolving Dox hydrochloride in DMSO and adding Triethylamine to the resulting solution. The purification is done using dialysis (incase of polymers). But I cannot do dialysis. 
Another method I tried was neutralizing the salt solution of Doxorubicin with PBS (pH 8.04), and centrifugation of the resulting mixture. But centrifugation yielded no pellet.

Comment: I would imagine this compound is soluble in diethylether or dichloromethane. You can probably do a standard acidification with 1M HCL and then extract into such an organic solvent. Hard to know how much detail to provide here because I don't know your experimental skill level or experience.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add a base to an aqueous solution of the compound.  The base could be ammonia water or ammonium hydroxide.  Make sure you add enough base to raise the pH to 12 or higher.
2. Add a water-immiscible organic solvent with a low boiling point to the solution and mix well.  A good solvent might be dichloromethane.
3. Let the phases separate and carefully remove the organic phase.  (If you use dichloromethane, the organic phase will be the bottom phase, but this is not true of all solvents.)
4. Repeat step 2 several times, each time combining the newest organic extract phase with the extract from the previous steps.
5. Evaporate the solvent under air, or, if you have it, an inert gas such as nitrogen.